# Why new element is hidden when old element which the new element appended to is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My purpose is to load image dynamically, and I'm using jQuery.
Let's say in a web page their is a `<fieldset>` element which contains 5 images, and there are two links(linkA and linkB) below the `<fieldset>`. When mouse hover on linkA, I like to load5 images are loaded from server A and showed in the `<fieldset>`; when hover on linkB, 5 images from server B showed in the `<fieldset>`.

My implementation is to create the `<fieldset>A` for images set A when mouse hovers on the linkA the first time; when mouse move to linkB, hide `<fieldset>A`, then create `<fieldset>B` and load images set B. when mouse back to linkA, hide `<fieldset>B` and show `<fieldset>A`.

Here is my problem, when page is loaded and I move mouse over linkA, the page act as expect ion, but when mouse move to linkB, I append `<fieldset>B` to `<fieldset>A` and hide `<fieldset>A`, `<fieldset>B` doesn't show either.

Below is the code: fieldA has been created

```
$.ajax({url:dUrl, success:function(result){
    var fieldB = $("<fieldset></fieldset>");
    fieldB.attr("id", cPath);
    fieldB.html(result);
    fieldA.append(fieldB);
    fieldA.hide();
}});
```

I'm new to web programing, is this a wrong way to use jQuery? Is this a wrong way to implement the dynamically loading pictures? Could anyone give me a help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is it dark at night ? I don't want to be rude, but if you *append* a node to another node which is hidden, why do you expect that any *childNode* will be visible ? That makes no sense at all, does it ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.append`(which adds an element inside other) you should try using `.after`(appends element after the given element).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I mix up .append and .after, ask a stupid question. ;)